# Make Solr ignore a trailing slash?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an indexed field `url` where some of my docs have a trailing slash at the end of their `url` field, others do not. I want to query this field in Solr while ignoring the trailing slash, so that all matching results come back regardless if they have a trailing slash at the end or not.

For example, if I send query: `q=url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test/` I want to get back any docs that have `url` field of `https://www.test.com/api/v1/test/` OR `https://www.test.com/api/v1/test`.

Similarly, if I send query without a trailing slash, I want the same results as above (`url` with OR without trailing slash).

How can this be done? I know about Solr wildcard feature, but I do not want to ignore any ending character (e.g. `url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test?` should not return docs with `url` of `https://www.test.com/api/v1/test`). I only want this wildcard effect for one trailing slash.

If it helps, I am on Solr 4 (yes I know it is old).

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a Regex replacement upon indexing, and replace `^(.*)(?:\/)?$` with `$1`...

Given these as input:

```
url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test?
url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test/
url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test
```

it ought to store:

```
url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test?
url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test
url:https://www.test.com/api/v1/test
```

If you then do the same replacement on querying, your queries should match as expected: queries with or without a trailing slash will match stored URLs with or without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PathHierarchyTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/tokenizers.html#path-hierarchy-tokenizer) for this. As a plus, you could then also search on parts of the URL without the need of wildcards.

e.g. `q=url:www.test.com` would also match the indexed URL.

This requires a suitable fieldType in your **schema.xml**

```xml
<fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then add or alter the field definition of your documents to use that `url` fieldType, also in the **schema.xml**

```xml
<field name="url" type="url" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for (a Tokenizer or something similar), but I do not want `q=url:www.test.com` to match an indexed URL of something like `https://www.test.com/api/v1/test/`. Is there a way to modify this Tokenizer to only ignore the trailing slash, nothing else?

Comment: No, I don't think so.